# C: How to discern between a string and integer? Output is printing ints fine, but not for strings

Tags: c, string, if-statement, input, boolean

My program tokenizes a string of input from the user, and from those tokens, discern whether or not they are a string or int(if any alphabetical character is attached to a number, meaning it is adjacent to any number - it is then treated as a string).

Hence, the following **input:** "*this is 1string 123 1*", should output `STR STR STR INT INT`. What I did: take the input string, proceed to tokenize/split it(with a space delimiter), and then iterate through the split token(using a for loop) to see whether or not the split token, has any character from the alphabet(upper-case or lower-case).

Now, that last sentence is the problem. I have a boolean called foundChar. If any alphabetical characters were found, then I would set foundChar to true. From there, I would do a simple if check to see if foundChar == true. However, now when I input a string, it prints blanks? I'm not sure if the way I'm using booleans is correct in C, or where to exactly pinpoint what is going wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// main
int main (void)
{
    // declare our stuff for stuffs
    char string[255];
    char *tokenizedString;
    const char delimiter[2] = " ";
    char *pch;
    bool found = false;
    int truth = 0;

    // prompt our user
    do {
        do {
            printf (">");
            fgets (string, 65, stdin);

        } while (strlen (string) <= 0);

        // remove it "\n" so it can terminate from newline input
        pch = strstr (string, "\n");
        strncpy (pch, "\0", 1);

        // tokenize the input string
        tokenizedString = strtok (string, delimiter);

        while (tokenizedString != NULL) {

            // check for any character in the token
            // if found = true, then it's a string by our premade definition 
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen (tokenizedString); i++) {
                if ((i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')
                    || (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z')) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            // if we find a char in the string
            if (found == true) {
                printf ("STR ");
            }

            // if the token is a number
            else if (isdigit (*tokenizedString))
                printf ("INT ");

            tokenizedString = strtok (NULL, delimiter);

            // reset charFound to zero for our next token
            found = false;

        }

        printf ("\n");

    } while (!(strlen (string) == 0));
} // end of program
```

**OUTPUT**

```
./prog why are
```

_________(nothing actually prints here, blank!  `STR STR` should print, same for the next string below!)

```
./prog  you not printing output for string
```

_________(nothing prints here as well, should print STR STR STR STR STR STR)

```
./prog 123
INT 

./prog 1st
INT 

./prog nor printing the right stuff
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
./prog why are
STR STR

./prog you not printing output for string
STR STR STR STR STR STR

./prog 123
INT 

./prog 1st
STR

./prog nor printing the right stuff
STR STR STR STR STR
```

Comment: `(i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')` --> `(tokenizedString[i] >= 'a' && tokenizedString[i] <= 'z')`

Comment: Why check for letters? I'd do the opposite. Check for digits using `isdigit()`, and treat anything that doesn't pass as a string character.

Comment: Ah, thank you, sorry about that. I didn't catch it, was looking at it for hours.

Comment: Well, even though the complexity of it is ridiculous, I thought it was a neat idea at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BLUEPIXY has correctly pointed out (as usual) the need to check whether the character in the `tokenizedString` is a digit or char, let's step back a bit and look at what you are doing from the big picture. While there is nothing wrong with tokenizing each string read and then iterating over each character in each token -- there is also no need for it.

All you really care about is whether each word in the line is made up solely of digits (for your `INT` output), otherwise you classify it as a `STR`. To do so, all you need to do is iterate over each character in your input and count the number of characters and digits between the spaces contained in the line. You can do so without any tokenization. Just keep count of the number of characters and number of digits encountered between each space you find (or those between the last space and the `'\n'` included in your input by `fgets`).

For example, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXS 256

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXS] = "";

    while (fgets (str, MAXS, stdin)) {      /* read each line */
        char *p = str;
        int ch = 0, dig = 0;
        while (*p) {                        /* for each char  */
            if (*p == ' ' || *p == '\n') {  /* if space or \n */
                if (ch)                     /* if char found  */
                    printf (" STR");
                else if (dig)               /* if digit found */
                    printf (" INT");
            }
            /* are we a char? */
            if (('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z') || ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z'))
                ch++;   /* incriment ch  */
            else if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')    /* are we a digit? */
                dig++;  /* incriment dig */
            p++;
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_or_int
why are
 STR STR
you not printing output for string
 STR STR STR STR STR STR
123
 INT
1st
 STR
nor printing the right stuff
 STR STR STR STR STR
```

Again, there is nothing wrong with tokenizing and then scanning each token, but it may be a bit more complicated than it need be. Look things over, incorporate the fix suggested by BLUEPIXY in your code, and compare the versions. Generally if there is a simple way to do something, you have a lot less chance of stumbling into a subtle error than you do if you take the long way around `:)`

Let me know if you have any further questions on either version.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your thorough answer. a little confused about the if(ch), else if (dig). It appears their types aren't stated, they're simply int types. What you're doing is  pointing a char type p at the beginning of the string, I understand that, then you've initialized ch and dig. I don't quite understand what you are comparing ch and dig to, INSIDE of the condition? It's almost as if you're using the int type as a boolean? also, why are you incrementing the values, it's almost as if you're using ch++ and dig++ like counters...

Comment: Hi David. I was able to take a look at BLUEPIXY's example, and solve the problem! However, I am getting a new error stating that there is no newline at the end of file. This leads me to believe that my tester does not want me to have a continuous stream of input, just one run.

Expected output
-------------------------
> one 1 4word other5
STR INT STR STR
-------------------------
Program output...
-------------------------
>one 1 4word other5
STR INT STR STR
>
-------------------------
Error: No newline at end of file

Comment: Sorry, just got back. `ch` and `dig` are declared **within** the `while` loop. They are only needed *within the scope* of the loop. Declaring variables in the proper scope is good practice. If I needed their values after the loop exited, then I would declare them at the top. POSIX requires a newline as the final line of every file (or program output) Just add a `putchar ('\n');` at the end. There are a number of reasons why this is a good requirement (not the least of which to not leave a partial line of text before your prompt when the program completes)

Comment: I'm am just checking that they are not zero. `if (ch)` is just shorthand for `if (ch != 0)` -- less typing, I am not great at typing, so I tend to use the shorthand when available. In the loop, if a character is found, I add `1` to `ch` (same for `dig` with digits). `if (ch)` is just checking "*Did I find any characters after the last space and before this one?*" (**note:** in the comment above, it should read "POSIX requires a newline at the end of the final line in a file (or program output)") Not all programs (or files) comply. Glad your prof is checking `:)`

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking out the time to reply! Didn't realize that was shorthand notation.

Comment: For completeness, it is also useful to think about it in terms of how conditionals are evaluated. In C, with `if (condition)`, condition evaluates `TRUE` for any *non-zero* value (or *non-NULL* value for pointers). So `if (ch)` evaluates `TRUE` for any non-zero value of `ch`. You can use to `!` operator in front of `ch` to check if it **is** zero as well. `if (!ch)` evaluates `TRUE` if `ch` is zero (because not-zero evaluate to `1` -- `TRUE`)